# how should I deal with assert failure?

Tags: c++

is there a correct or accepted way to deal with assert failure in debug / release mode?

For instance:
let's say I have a function that returns a std::vector

I expect the length of the returned vector to be equal to another object's, and I do this:

```
std::vector<int> v = get_stuff();
ASSERT(v.size() == this->size() )
a = v[this->size() - 1 ];
```

now this code will work fine if no assertion is triggered, and in debug this could crash but at least I would have the assertion failure warning me that something is wrong.
The problem would be in release mode, where there would be a silent crash.
Does this mean that I have to also check for this error in the release code and then handle it? it's possible but then I see no point in adding an assertion failure over it, since it is handled

Comment: If the assert fires, you must find out why and fix it. The idea is that by testing enough in debug, you'll catch all the cases where the assert fires, fixing all the bugs for release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `assert` has a different meaning than you appear to think. It's not a substitute for an exception, which I think is how you think of it. It's there so that you can spot trouble early on in debug. If you get the assert in debug, you fix it. Then you test. And then test again. And make sure the condition would hold in release. If it does... well, you've got a bug.

> Does this mean that I have to also check for this error in the release code and then handle it?

If you expect it to happen, yes. Check the condition, throw an exception, and handle it delicately. Send an error report. Write to a log file. Update the software.

Answer (score 1):

Assertions are for conditions that must invariably be true. Not for exception handling.

They reflect assumptions that you made during design. If there is *any legal* possibility for `get_stuff` to return a vector of wrong size, you have to handle that separately.

Comment: I was just going to post a similar answer: Assertions are for *invariants* in your program. They must always hold true.

Comment: I like turning them into exceptions. They may be invariants, that does not mean they will not vary. Many commercial software companies have crash dumps that *could not happen*. And yet, they happened. A bug? A RAM bit-flip? Many things are possible.

Comment: @JesseGood: A *condition that is invariably true* is an invariant :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not limited to the assert provided by the C library, and it can make sense to have an additional assertion mechanism that still operates in a production/release build:

- use the C library `assert` for expensive (CPU, cache hosing, database load...) checks that you don't want to slow down your production/release builds
- use your own assert mechanism for cheap or critically important tests that you want to run even in production/release builds, where failure indicates your program can't be trusted to operate properly thereafter: for example, if a data structure that's core to your program operation is clearly corrupted
- use exceptions / error codes etc when you think you can report an error and get back to a useful state for doing further work, and it's a priority to keep offering that service

So, in your example:

```
std::vector<int> v = get_stuff();
ASSERT(v.size() == this->size());
a = v[this->size() - 1];
```

You could use an ASSERT that's debug mode only, an ASSERT that'll kick in in production too, or follow the former with...

```
a = v.at(this->size() - 1);
```

...such that you get an exception you can catch and handle if the problem arrises in production.  To get code coverage for your exception handling case you'll need to create a unit test case for the production build.

Something to keep in mind is finding a realistic and maintainable balance: if you try to be too exhaustive in your run-time error handling your code can blow out to 5 or 10 times the size and complexity, and your testing effort too.  So be selective in where you handle and to what extent.  Simply asserting and core dumping etc. is relatively simple: a one liner with no test case, and can be used more liberally.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to include the ASSERT (for debug) followed by code that handles the error.  In a debug run, the assertion failures brings the system to a halt and lets me see the problem immediately.  Then in release builds, the code that handles the error situation still runs. The code that handles the error has to be thought out some of course.  It might make sense to produce a crash dump file (minidump in Windows, core dump in Linux).

Comment: No biggie, but one thing to keep in mind when doing this is that if the release build "handles the error situation" code is vaguely complex then you will want code coverage during testing, which means running that test case against a release build so the assert doesn't kick in first.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: I think that is a good point.  On the other hand, an ASSERT may imply the condition should not be possible to hit, which sort of implies that it would be impossible to hit in a test case as well.

Comment: assertions may sometimes be used for documentation for things that are momentarily clearly impossible, but that's a spectrum and as code's maintained and evolved the assertion may become possible. Whether you bother to code for that situation is a judgement call, but what I'm saying is that if you do bother, then it's worth thinking about how to "inject" a failure in a unit test case so you can get code coverage. Often error handling code fails to help in production because it's never exercised in testing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to "deal" with three kinds of errors in your program, I personally prefer to handle and classify them in the following way (ymmv):

- Errors that are expected to occur quite frequently (e.g. bad user input). They might be (partially) recoverable. I usually handle them via checks/error codes, occasionally via exceptions.
- Exceptional errors that are detected, but are usually not expected. I always use exceptions for them, they usually make operations fail on a larger scale.
- Erros that may not occur; that are "impossible" to happen. Like in your vector class, you would expect people to use a proper index. You don't want to spend precious cycles to check those conditions in release mode, but when it is easy to detect those things, do it in debug mode to provide a better alternative to a hard-to-debug crash (e.g. by using `assert(condition && "explanation of why you asser the condition here and what it means that it is violated")`.

I usually test preconditions to functions with asserts, e.g. that some pointers are non-null, or that values are within range. I sprinkle them around generously, so that in debug mode (where all my tests and unit-tests are running in) these bugs can be found. It is a bit like a "detect undefined behaviour" mode that quite some standard libraries have.